# JQuery improve animation() performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am working on a page design, that has on the left side 1 big div and on the right side 6 smaller ones lined up. When I click on one of the right side divs, the content from that div transitions to the left and the former big one appears on the right side. For that I wrote a animation with JQuery that moves my left side div to the position of the element I clicked on,hides it and then expands it back to its original position. The problem that I have with it is that it works just fine on Chrome, but when I try it out on Firefox, the animation is lagging. How can I improve the performance of the animation across different browsers?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".small").click(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var pusher = offset.top - 54;
    $("div.left-side").css({'height': '129', 'left': '40%', 'top':  offset, 'opacity': '0'});
    $("div.left-side").animate({'left': '0%','top': '0', 'height': '800', 'opacity': '1'}, 500);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".container").offset().top}, 500);
  });
});
```

Here would be my complete code at the moment I'm working on: 
https://github.com/renepickhardt/metalcon/tree/feature/frontend/basic_page_template
The relevant parts for the question would be in main.html, contentswap2.js and style.css.
I tried to boil the question down to the essence, but I guess that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Please provide your html and CSS. How you have defined your layout will have an impact on performance as well

Comment: @user2747192 I had this exact problem not to long ago. Your going to get much smoother animations with css3 transitions and transformations. If you haven't seen it yet, check this out transit: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a quite heavy animation dependent on the rest of your HTML...

Anyhow you can try to add `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)` to your .css() part, so:

```
$("div.left-side").css({'transform': 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)', 'height': '129', 'left': '40%', 'top':  offset, 'opacity': '0'});
```

But don't forget about the browser prefixes: -webkit, -moz, ... if you expect old browsers.

This trick actually forces hardware acceleration by sending stuff to the GPU which renders faster, doesn't work though in all/older browsers...